# How do I clean up order data with Node.js to exclude cancelled items identified only by negative value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have order data that I need to clean up so that it will only include items not returned by customers.

The returned goods show up in the data as two lines, one with positive `productPrice` and one with negative. See example below where order with id `1102` has a returned item with `productId 1767` and order `1103` has returned item `1782`:

```
{ _id: '1101',
  ...
  products: 
   [ { productId: '1509',
       productPrice: '69.9' } ] }
{ _id: '1102',
  ...
  products: 
   [ { productId: '1682',
       productPrice: '59.9' },
     { productId: '1767',           // Original
       productPrice: '119' },
     { productId: '1767',           // Return
       productPrice: '-119' } ] }  
{ _id: '1103',
  ...
  products: 
   [ { productId: '1782',           // Original
       productPrice: '79.9' },
     { productId: '1782',           // Return
       productPrice: '-79.9' } ] }
```

I want to remove all the returned items from the data and delete orders without any products left after cleanup.

The end result would look something like this:

```
{ _id: '1101',
  ...
  products: 
   [ { productId: '1509',
       productPrice: '69.9' } ] }
{ _id: '1102',
  ...
  products: 
   [ { productId: '1682',
       productPrice: '59.9' } ] }
```

I'm not sure how I can achieve this with Node.js so any help would be appreciated. The order data is stored in a Mongo DB if that's any help.

---

**UPDATE: Current code with partial solution**

Got some help from a friend and now the code cleans up the cancelled products:

```
// Clean up Orders
const cleanUpOrders = (order) => {
  function removeReturnedProductsFromOrder(order){
    var products = [];
    var returnedProducts = getReturnedOrderProducts(order);
    _.each(order.products, function (product) {
      if( getProductFromList(product, returnedProducts) === undefined ){
        products.push(product);
      }
    });
    order.products = products;
    return order;
  }
  function getReturnedOrderProducts(order) {
    return _.filter(order.products, function (product) {
      return product.productPrice < 0;
    });
  }
  function getProductFromList(product, returnedProducts) {
    return _.find(returnedProducts, function(p) {
      return p.productId === product.productId;
    });
  }
  removeReturnedProductsFromOrder(order);
  return order;
};

// Decorate Products
const decorateProducts = (order) => {
  const decorateItem = (item) => {
    return collectionProducts.findOne({"_id": item.productId})
    .then(currentProduct => {
      if (currentProduct) {
        item.productTitle = currentProduct["productTitle"];
        item.productImageUrl = currentProduct["productImageUrl"];
        item.productUrl = currentProduct["productUrl"];
        return order;
      }     
    });
  }
  var actions = order.products.map(decorateItem); 
  return Promise.all(actions);
};

router.get('/:From-:To', function(req, res, next) {
  var csvFrom = moment(req.params.From).unix();
  var csvTo = moment(req.params.To).unix();  
  collectionOrders.find({ $and: [ {"timestamp" : { $gte: csvFrom }} , {"timestamp" : { $lte: csvTo }} ] })
  .then(orders => Promise.all(orders.map(order => decorateProducts(order))))
  .then(output => res.send(output))
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
});
```

Last thing to do is to clean up empty orders from the data.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: @NathanP.: I tried to find a proper approach to this problem with google, but couldn't find suitable method as it's multilevel array which has multiple items. So I'm not sure how to tackle this problem as working with arrays and Node.js is new to me. Even nudge to the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to go through the first list in order to go through the second one, find matching ID's and finally check if values sum to 0, or something like that. You'll have to show us some code in order to help you to fix it :)

Comment: @NathanP.: I've added the current code to the question.